# Does $(1+\frac12-\frac13) + (\frac14+\frac15-\frac16)+(\frac17+\frac18-\frac19)+\cdots$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> Does the series $$S=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3} \right) + \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6} \right)+\left(\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}\right)+\cdots$$ converge?

Here's my attempt at a solution: $$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

As we can "rewrite" this series as one third of the harmonical series (that diverges), we conclude the divergence of $S$.

Is this right? Which other convergence tests could be used?

Comment: your solution is not correct. You cannot change the order of summation of a series that doesn't converge absolutely, neither make (standard) arithmetic with divergent series

Comment: @Masacroso Is it not fine to do something along the lines of " Suppose the following series converges. Then in particular, it converges absolutely, so we can reorder the series in any way. One particular ordering gives a scalar multiple of the harmonic series which diverges, so the given series cannot converge".

Comment: @Saad That is not a valid argument because convergence doesn't imply absolute convergence (you've got it the wrong way round).

Comment: Of course, you're correct. For whatever reason, I thought each term was positive..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but your reasoning is not.  Order matters.  You should write the sum as follows:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}-\frac{1}{3n+3}\right)$$
Simplify what is in the parentheses and then evaluate in the usual way.

Oh, and it is true that order does *not* matter if all the terms are positive.  But when some terms are positive and others negative, you have to be more careful.

Comment: In this case you can simply say $\frac 1{3n+2}-\frac 1{3n+3}>0$ thus the series is $>\sum\frac 1{3n+1}$ which is a divergent series. I mean we do not even need to calculate that the parenthesis is equivalent to $\frac {9n^2}{27n^3}$.

Comment: @zwim quite true, that is a nice little shortcut

Comment: Simplify and it behaves like $1/n$, so it diverges.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is correct, but you cannot write like that, because the series involved are both divergent and generally it is moot to do arithmetic operations of divergent series.

Let $H_n = \sum_1^n 1/k$, i.e. the $n$-th partial sum of the harmonic series, then the 
$$
S_n = H_{3n} - \frac 23 H_n, 
$$
then use the asymptotic expression $H_n = \log n + \gamma + \varepsilon_n$ where $\varepsilon_n \to 0 [n \to \infty]$, we have
$$
S_n = \log (3n) -\frac 23\log n + \frac 13 \gamma + \varepsilon_{3n} - \frac 23 \varepsilon_n = \log(3n^{1/3}) + \frac 13 \gamma + \alpha_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} +\infty. 
$$